# Help solving a Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dx}{dt} = x-4y$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=4x=7y$

I found the eigenvalue to be $-3$ and the general solution to be $x=e^{3t} x_{initial} +te^{3t}(-2x-7y)$ and $y= e^{3t} y_{initial}+ te^{3t} (-x+y)$

Determine the particular solution for $x(0)=10$ and $y(0)=0$ how do I plug these initial equations into the general solution? Also, what would the phase plane for this system of equations look like.